# benchmarking a vps system

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, web-hosting, benchmark

I've been having some performance problmes lately with my ecommerce package (ASP.net + SQL Server) running on Hyper-V based VPS so I am thinking about switching my VPS for a faster one.

To evaluate a VPS before migration I need a simple (preferably free or inexpensive) benchmark that would test come CPU/mem/disk performance and could be run on windows (VPS).

A nice-to-have feature would be ability to take into account server load. In essence I am looking for something that can take into account that server CPU is on average 80% loaded and take that into account when producing a score.

I hope I am making sense :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running Hyper-V and wish to look at the performance on its current machine then I recommend the following article on [How to Monitor Hyper-V Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tvoellm/archive/2009/04/23/monitoring-hyper-v-performance.aspx).  Has come in handy in the past.  I am not aware of any tools that can look at the performance of the Hyper-V layer which are inexpensive.